# Using jquery to change checkbox status

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, state

I have a list of items that have checkboxes associated with them, and the items are beneath a list header, which also has a checkbox(for db purposes only) which is actually hidden from view. I need to make it so that if *any* of the checkboxes beneath the header is checked, then the header checkbox is checked as well. BUT I also need to make it so that if *all* of the checkboxes are unchecked, then the header one is unchecked...how hard is this going to be?

This is how I have it setup now:

```
if($('.childCheckBox').is(":checked")){
$('#parentBox').attr('checked', true);
}
```

Now I am thinking that if I were to do something where I add an else if clause:

```
else if($('.proBox2').is(not)(":checked"){
alert("uncheck parent");
}
```

But I don't know the correct syntax for is-not, or isn't, or even if there is anything that will do that. Are there any thoughts out there? I need the box to check if one is selected and uncheck if none are selected. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.proBox2').is(':not(:checked)')
```

Also, I'm not so sure about the first one.  It *may* work, but I'd probably do it like this if it doesn't:

```
$('.childCheckBox:checked').length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **not()** selector:

```
else if($('.proBox2').is(":not(:checked)")
```

Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) about the not selector.

Comment: Should be `:not` and not `not`, if i'm not not not mistaken