# How to check and uncheck checkbox elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I'm using the `.attr()` jQuery function to check and uncheck checkboxes. It work the first time but then it doesn't any more.

After read several questions about it I just can-t make this work. e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5229023/1505348) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901712/1505348) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2898634/1505348)

I tested it on Chrome and Firefox. I get the same problems using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULSeZ/1/).

Where is the problem? On the JavaScript code, in HTML or where?

This is all the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Searchs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results-body">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="small center">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" onclick="master();" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="center">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="slave" onclick="slave();" />
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="center">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="slave" onclick="slave();" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- LOAD THE JS AT THE END OF THE FILE -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            master = function() {
                if ($( '#checkall:checkbox' ).is(":checked"))
                    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);
                else
                    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
            }
            slave = function() {
                var allSelected = true;
                $( '.slave[type="checkbox"]' ).each(function() {
                    if ($( this ).is(":not(:checked)")){
                        allSelected = false;
                        //return;
                    }
                });
                if (!allSelected) {
                    //$( '#checkall:checkbox' ).removeAttr('checked');
                    alert("REMOVE: \nFrom " + $( '#checkall:checkbox' ).attr('checked') );
                    $( '#checkall:checkbox' ).attr('checked',false);
                    alert("to " + $( '#checkall:checkbox' ).attr('checked') );

                } else {
                    alert("ADD: \nFrom " + $( '#checkall:checkbox' ).attr('checked') );
                    $( '#checkall:checkbox' ).attr('checked',true);
                    alert("to " + $( '#checkall:checkbox' ).attr('checked') );
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: swap out `.attr` with `.prop`

Comment: @adeneo That worked. Please create a new answer so I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `.prop()` when setting properties like `checked`, so change :

```
.attr('checked', true)
```

to

```
.prop('checked', true)
```

and stuff like :

```
$( '#checkall:checkbox' ).attr('checked')
```

with:

```
$( '#checkall:checkbox' ).is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 3):

Change all your `.attr()` to `.prop()`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ULSeZ/2/)**

As the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) say (beginning with 1.9):

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected,
>   or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Comment: That is way it have worked for me before, because I'd used the `1.8` version, but now it doesn't work since the `1.9` version. Really interesting